# CentOS6 - How to install Postfix with MySQL support from "centosplus repository"?

Tags: postfix, centos6

I need to install Postfix with MySQL support from the CentOSPlus repository.

I have done what this document/tutorial describes: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28ve%29:Install_Postfix_with_Dovecot_on_CentOS

And when I try to do "yum install postfix" I got this:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package postfix available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any clues on how to install Postfix from CentOsPlus Repos?

Best Regards,

Comment: they dont since centos 6 plus does not offer postfix.
use rpmforge or build your own package for centos.

Comment: My postfix on CentOS 6.3 installed from Base repo has mysql capability and supports dovecot authentication as well.

Comment: That's not true. I installed from Base repository and has no Mysql support. And it looks like centosplus has no package with mysql support

Answer (score 2):

The centosplus repo may not be enabled in your configuration. Can you try: `yum --enablerepo=centosplus install postfix` first?

A more permanent fix may be modifying the `/etc/yum/repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file to enable the centosplus repository; set "enabled=1".

Looking at the [link you posted](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28ve%29:Install_Postfix_with_Dovecot_on_CentOS), there's detailed information about excluding postfix from the base repo and enabling the centosplus repository. Those instructions should work.

Comment: this didnt work for me, i got no package in the centos plus too.. then updates/primary_db                                                                                                                                                            | 3.9 MB     00:00
Package 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package postfix-mysql available.
No package dovecot-core available.
No package dovecot-imapd available.
No package dovecot-lmtpd available.
Package 1:dovecot-mysql-2.0.9-8.el6_6.4.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Answer (score 1):

I faced the very same problem in my CentOS 6.4 machine.

According to [this URL](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/print.php?form=1&topic_id=37632&forum=56&order=ASC&start=0) in CentOS forums, "Postfix in CentOS 6 is already mysql enabled in the base repo, there's no need to look for a special version.".

Regards.